# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when transferring data from jdbc to elasticsearch via logstash

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, heap-memory

I have a huge postgres database with 20 million rows and i want to transfer it to elasticsearch via logstash . I followed the advice mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/aggregate-and-index-data-into-elasticsearch-using) and I test it for a simple database with 300 rows and all things worked fine but when i tested it for my main database i allways  cross with error:

```
nargess@nargess-Surface-Book:/usr/share/logstash/bin$  sudo ./logstash -w 1 -f students.conf --path.data /usr/share/logstash/data/students/ --path.settings /etc/logstash
Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid3453.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [13385912484 bytes in 53.304 secs]
Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-11: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.16.0-java/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:216"  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.popRubyClass(ThreadContext.java:729)
at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.postYield(ThreadContext.java:1292)
at org.jruby.runtime.ContextAwareBlockBody.post(ContextAwareBlockBody.java:29)
at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:198)
at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:300)
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:230)
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
The signal INT is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
Error: Your application used more memory than the safety cap of 12G.
Specify -J-Xmx####m to increase it (#### = cap size in MB).
Specify -w for full OutOfMemoryError stack trace
```

Although I go  to file /etc/logstash/jvm.options and set `-Xms256m
-Xmx12000m`, but I have had these errors yet. I have 13g memory free. how can i send my data to elastic search with this memory ? 
this is the student-index.json that i use in elasticsearch

```
{
"aliases": {},
"warmers": {},
"mappings": {
    "tab_students_dfe": {
        "properties": {
            "stcode": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "voroodi": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "family": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "namp": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "lastupdate": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "picture": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "uniquename": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
}
}
```

then i try to insert this index in elastic search by :

```
curl -XPUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" 

http://localhost:9200/students -d @postgres-index.json
```

and next, this is my configuration fil in /usr/shar/logstash/bin/students.conf file :

```
input {
  jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
jdbc_user => "postgres"
jdbc_password => "postgres"
# The path to downloaded jdbc driver
jdbc_driver_library => "./postgresql-42.2.1.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
# The path to the file containing the query
statement => "select * from students"
  }
}
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{stcode}"
code => "
  map['stcode'] = event.get('stcode')
  map['voroodi'] = event.get('voroodi')
  map['name'] = event.get('name')
  map['family'] = event.get('family')
  map['namp'] = event.get('namp')
  map['uniquename'] = event.get('uniquename')
  event.cancel()
"
push_previous_map_as_event => true
timeout => 5
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
document_id => "%{stcode}"
document_type => "postgres"
index => "students"
codec => "json"
hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably a programming error. Instead of caching everything in memory, you should load and transfer it in chunks.

Comment: Post the code that you are using and also use small batches to push data into Elastic Search and keep track of rows you have pushed in.

Comment: Also why are you using only one worker thread?

Comment: I edited the question . In fact , i don't know how many worker I should use . I just write one worker because of the link mentioned it .

Comment: Ok. Apparently it's because of the aggregation.

Comment: I thought aggregations was necessary for transferring data from sql to elasticsearch. isn't it ?

Comment: actually i test with 7 worker because i my system is corei7 but it don't make any change it performance . How can I reduce memory usage in this process?

Comment: @baudsp i removed aggregation but again i have outOfMemoryError

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I just had the same issue and increasing the heap size of logstash helped me here. I added this to my logstash service in the docker-compose file:

```
environment:
  LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
```

Further read: [What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm)